# Chess match between two smartphones

Tags: engines, computer-chess

I have two smartphones with different CPUs, GPUs, RAM etc...

How can I put them to play a chess match each other? By using different chess engines or the same one, with choosing CPU or GPU.

For example: Stockfish 15 in phone A GPU vs Stockfish 14 in phone B CPU.

Edit: They should play each other automatically, not manually by a human who will "transfer" the moves to each phone.

Comment: Sorry, what is the relevance to your question of the phones having different hardware?

Comment: Setup some kind of communication channel and run CuteChess

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it manually,

You can install an engine of your choice onto each phone, start a match on each phone (one where the engine is playing white, and one where it is playing black) and simply input the first engine's move into the second engine, input its reply back into the first one and so on.

To do it automatically,

You can use the Universal Chess Interface. What exactly to do will depend on your specific use case and needs but you can read more about it [here](https://www.chessprogramming.org/UCI).

Comment: yes, I mean this, not manually but automatically.

Comment: @SEnergeiakos Sorry for the misunderstanding, please see my edited answer.